# Gradient effects of a function

Tags: flash, function, gradient, blur

I want to apply a blur filter to an image in Flash CS4. I understand how to apply the filer but is there a way to apply it in differing amounts to different parts of the image? I want to have the edges very blurry while I want the center to stay relatively sharp (apply the blur filter as if it were a gradient coming from the center out).

Answer (score 1):

Use Pixeleros pixel bender filter [here](http://pixelero.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/pixel-bender-blur-with-linear-focus/).

The solution Adam Harte gave is simpler if you're gonna cheat with a little less blur, but it looks really wrong if you want to want have something similar to the depth-of-field effect of a camera.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do it in multiple passes.  Basically generate a bunch of BitmapData objects of each successively smaller rectangle of image area.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look at [Adobe Pixel Bender](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbender/), create your own filter for Flash and apply it to the image.

Answer (score 0):

To get this effect, you will need three layers. Here are the layers from **bottom to top**:

1. The original non-blurred image (bottom most layer).
2. Copy of the original image, with the full blur applied.
3. Gradient mask. Create a shape with a black and white fill of the gradient you want (needs to be in a movieclip), and place it over the top. You can then use it to mask the blur layer (you will need to apply the mask using Actionscript, because that is [**the only way you can have a gradient mask**](http://genaboo.wordpress.com/2008/03/23/alpha-gradient-masks/)).

You can choose to either mask the original image or the blurred one, but the mask layer will need to be on top of the non-masked layer.

Hope this helps.